# Convert specific cell array elements to array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell

I have a problem when trying to convert a sequnce of cell array's elements into a matrix in Matlab. In particular, I execute the folllowing command for taking the elements I want from the `cell_array[]` (note that although I've put `11` as a constant here, it actually varies depending on other things but it's known when I execute the command):

> cell_array{3, 2:2:11,1}

which gives the following result:

```
ans =
                     0.173

ans =
                     0.188

ans =
                      0.06

ans =
                     0.165

ans =
                     0.225
```

In order to put the above elements into an array `C`, I have tried using `vec2mat` but it didn't work:

```
C=vec2mat((cell_array{3, 2:2:11,1}),5)
Error using vec2mat
Too many input arguments
```

Also, when I try that:

```
C=cell_array{3, 2:2:11,1})
```

only the first element is strored in `C`:

```
C =
                 0.173
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just

```
C = [cell_array{3, 2:2:11,1}]
```

(that is, enclose the expression inside square brackets)